# are these attempted injections on my contact form?

Tags: php, security, forms

I have a PHP contact form mailer on my website.  The contents don't store in a database, but are emailed directly to me.  I have received a couple strange contacts in the last few days.

The user has to fill in name, email, confirm email subject and message.

I have a javascript security in place that verifies an email is typed in the same twice, and checks for the @ and the dot.  Also, required fields are checked with javascript.

Here is the most recent message-you can see it is a bunch of bogus links, etc.  Is this anything I should be concerned of from a security standpoint?

```
Name: fvjnqazcy

Email: cervau@fbcalj.com

Email confirm: cervau@fbcalj.com

Phone: 47668113220

Subject: uSMvoegKPt

Message: KU17Gd  <a href="http://lsyixbpcjddi.com/">lsyixbpcjddi</a>,
[url=http://sojlxycrnxlb.com/]sojlxycrnxlb[/url], [link=http://wesixtcvuzbj.com/]wesixtcvuzbj[/link], http://dcgfyjhpfpbx.com/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks more like  a spammer to me. If you have more of these messages than you can handle, you need to add a CAPTCHA to your contact form. I don't think it's intended to exploit a potential security issue in your application though.

Comment: It's strange to me that the links and email don't actually go anywhere.  I don't understand how a spammer would benefit from this?

Comment: @Joel: Maybe the spammer is testing to see if can add something to your page by filling out that form and then use the actual URL if it worked.

Comment: Often a contact form will send an e-mail to the person who filled it out. Spammers use this tactic to find live e-mail addresses. I'll 2nd adding a captcha. After I added one, it killed the bots, but not the live spammers.

Comment: Ah good point...I have seen those on comment pages, etc.  Makes sense.

Comment: If (when) it gets out of hand, I'll look into a captcha.  I hate them, but I'll probably try and impliment one of those x + y = z type ones...

Comment: @Joel, are you sure that the To/CC/BCC address can't be manipulated to send spam to more than just you (injecting headers)? It would be bad if you acted as an open mail relay for phishing emails.

Comment: That would certainly be bad...how can I check this?

Comment: @Joel - you could try to exploit it yourself and add email headers by injection newline (\r\n). Just add an email account that you control and see if you get a copy in that account. Or if the site is public, point me to it.

Comment: Instead of the capthca, why dont try the honeypots technique? it doesnt annoy your user and it safe against all bots.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I agree with Mehrdad, it just looks like a random spam bot. Don't ask why they are doing that; I don't think there is a real reasoning for them to add spam..

> I have a javascript security in place that verifies an email is typed in the same twice, and checks for the @ and the dot. Also, required fields are checked with javascript.

You really shouldn't do *any* important checks with JavaScript. Or at least not without testing them on the server side as well.

JavaScript is easily disabled and then all your checks will fail. Especially bots *never* interpret JavaScript, so all your checks won't be made and all input is just accepted as it is.

To prevent spam in general you should gradually add more security checks on the server side. One rather hard option is adding a CAPTCHA, but moving those checks to your server first will probably help as well (given that the bot enters two different email addresses).